# Best sound format for iOS device? (iphone & iPad)

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, audio

Okay well i have alot of sounds on my app and just wondered what is the best audio format to use for the sounds?

Thanks

Comment: It depends on your needs. I use mp3 and aac.

Comment: oh do mp3's work? can they be played simitanously?

Comment: yes, but it will cause some performance overhead.

Answer (score 0):

If your app will mainly focus on audio then you have two paths.

1) Your app wants to do pretty intensive audio processing (filtering, effects, etc).  For this uncompressed audio is going to be your best bet.  Using wav files or raw PCM data require no decompression and thus can be read much faster.

2) Your app wants to do less intensive audio processing.  Simply mp3 or aac should be fine.

Also what will be your target devices?  There is a big difference between what the iPhone 4 can do and what the iPhone 3g can do.